# DRAM and its effects on real world performance

Tags: performance, cpu, frequency, ram

After learning a little on how computer programs run I had some thoughts concerning the cpu and RAM. After watching a few youtube videos (linus tech tips and others) they all seem to show that increasing a RAM speed (frequency) does not really have much of a performance improvement in real world applications and games on a general desktop computer. My first question is why is this? Is it because of the high hit rates (95% and above) of the cpu's cache on most modern cpus? Which in turn would lead to less and less need for the cpu to reach out to ram? Also, in which situations would faster RAM frequency be beneficial?

Comment: I also wonder why that is. Stall times for cache misses are enormous.

Comment: Could you provide a source that claims this? RAM is a tricky topic to discuss because its performance is related to _frequency_ component and a _timings_ component. I'd be surprised if anybody is claiming that lowering the latency to fulfil memory requests is not beneficial. It will undoubtedly be useful for most applications. Maybe they're referring to the frequencies of DRAM components.

Comment: @hayesti games benefit negligibly from RAM frequency. This has been determined by many benchmarks. Also, http://techbuyersguru.com/ramspeedgaming.php

Comment: @usr This is what I suspected. DRAM frequencies tend to relate more to the memory bandwidth whereas the DRAM timings relate more to the latency. It's more difficult to reduce DRAM latencies so manufacturers focus on increasing bandwidth. Many scalar applications actually have difficulty saturating memory bandwidth. This is changing with chip multiprocessors as several scalar applications now compete/share the available memory bandwidth.

Comment: Here are some videos that got me thinking about it on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utWnjA4NzSA (around the 5:08 mark is where he looks at some real world applications and the differences between DDR4 and DDR3) and this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWgzA2C61z4
which focuses more on games but still raised some questions for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: this is a very broad question, and the answers can vary very differently depending on the architecture/OS running the system. I am answering from a best-judgement standpoint on how these things generally work

1. Why is there not a larger performance difference between different RAM clock speeds?

I would imagine that the clock speed of the RAM of the computer matters less than the clock speed of the CPU cache. Because:

- the CPU gets its instructions from the cache, not straight from RAM
- with the larger cache sizes of modern CPU's, it is less necessary to need to go out to RAM as often.
- When the cache needs to go out to RAM, it uses an asynchronous processor (DMA) to grab more information, allowing the CPU to switch to a different process entirely.

Besides that, the clock speed of the motherboard's various pipelines (DMA) could be creating a chokepoint where it is slowing the transfer rate of the information overall.

2. > which situations would faster RAM frequency be beneficial?

I would say that overall, any one of the core pieces of hardware involved with memory and its use and transfer (CPU, CPU Cache, The Various memory pipelines, the various memory transfer devices (DMA, etc.), the RAM itself) can cause a chokepoint where faster RAM might or might not affect the overall performance. It is really a by-case issue.

Comment: Ya, the only thing I could reason as well for not being too much difference in RAM clock speeds had to do with the cpu just not needed to make many requests to RAM in a typical application. I wonder though if you had an application like a 3d modeling and rendering program or something else that requires alot of system resources, if faster RAM would be more beneficial?

Comment: Potentially. That is why GPU memory is special